# PHP GD Image Library change image color - gif works but jpegs wont

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

Thanks for taking the time to read my problem:

I'm using the following code to get an image and then change the color 201,2,255 (r,g,b) - which is a shade of purple then output the image.

```
$imgname = "input.gif";
$im = imagecreatefromgif ($imgname);

$index = imagecolorclosest ( $im,  201,2,255 ); // get White COlor
imagecolorset($im,$index,60,140,48); // SET NEW COLOR

$imgname = "output.gif";
imagegif($im, $imgname ); // save image as gif
imagedestroy($im);
```

This works perfectly which can be seen here : http://www.office-desks.co.uk/cache_images/test.php (top 2 images)

The problem is when I try todo exactly the same but using a jpeg instead it doesn't work.. (bottom 2 images)

```
$imgname = "input.jpg";
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg ($imgname);

$index = imagecolorclosest ( $im,  201,2,255 ); // get pink/purple COlor
imagecolorset($im,$index,60,140,48); // SET NEW DECENT COLOR

$imgname = "output.jpg";
imagejpeg($im, $imgname ); // save image as gif
imagedestroy($im);
```

If anyone could help me shed some light on the problem, would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance all.

Comment: Can you apply [imagetruecolortopalette](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagetruecolortopalette.php) to the resource prior to replacing the colour?

Comment: Thanks Anthony, do you have any examples of this in action? how do I implement into the above code?

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but I think that has to do with the 'artifacts' (compression errors) generated by JPG. Zoom in on a JPG and you see 'grains' of pixels that won't match the neighbors. This means big planes of a single color will become many colors and not 1 single value.

Stick with lossless image formats like gif or png.